# Read data from a database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have created a table name glossary in a database named `ChatBotDataBase` in SQL Server. I want to read the data in a special column of the table.

To do so, I have written this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        sc.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=shirin;Initial Catalog=ChatBotDataBase; 
        Integrated Security=True";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sda.SelectCommand.Connection = sc;

        sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM glossary";

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MessageBox.Show(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());
    }
```

But there is an error in last line.

The error is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

And here is a print screen of the mentioned table:[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You didn't even fill your `table`, that's why it doesn't have any `Rows[0]` and that's why it doesn't have any `ItemArray[3]`.

Comment: @SonerGönül I did. there is a row with 4 columns.

Comment: Use `Fill` for `sda` after creating `DataTable`. And get `sc` and `sda` into `using` because they implement `IDisposable`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing the `Datatable` called `table` with your database table in your sql server. In your image you show us the `glossary` table in your sql server, not the `DataTable` called `table`.

You get this error because you create an empty `DataTable` called `table` with `DataTable table = new DataTable()` but you didn't *even* fill your `table`. That's why it doesn't have *any* rows by default.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM glossary");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(table);
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

```
using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM glossary";
   ...
   using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      sda.Fill(table);

      if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         MessageBox.Show(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you suggested and now it works.I know it was foolish but you know I'm beginner in programming. :)

Answer (score 4):

Below code will help you

```
    sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM glossary";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(table , "glossary");
    MessageBox.Show(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't executed the query or populated the table. It is empty. It has no columns and no rows. Hence the error.

Frankly, though, I strongly suggest using a typed class model, not any kind of DataTable. With tools like "dapper", this can be as simple as:

```
var list = conn.Query<Glossary>("SELECT * FROM glossary").ToList();
```

With

```
public class Glossary {
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string String1 {get;set} // horrible name!
    ....
    public int NumberOfUse {get;set}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. Can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: @TTS probably ExecuteReader on the command, then Load(reader) on the table. However, I would advise an alternative approach (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("<connectionstring>");

OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("select * from TableX",con);

OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds,"New");

DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.DataSource = ds.Tables["New"];
```

you can get the connection string from:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: The `OdbcConnection`, `OdbcDataCommand` and `OdbcDataAdapter` should be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Dear kindly first fill your table with the data.
And you should use checks because if there is no data then you get a proper message.check is below..

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     MessageBox.Show(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString());
else if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Table is empty");
```

And other advice is that you should display data into DataGrid.... Displaying data from Database into a message box is not a good programming approach..

For displaying DataTable into DataGrid in C# is as simple as below.

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student",con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "students";
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource =dt;
```